# Is it possible to estimate polynomial from below?

Tags: polynomials

Let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial of the total degree $n$ s. t. $P(x,y) \ge 0$ and $P(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y=0.$
Does there exist a constant $C>0$ with the property $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\,\, \forall y \in \mathbb{R} \left( P(x,y) \ge C(|x| +|y|)^n\right) ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conclusion:**

1. $n$ must be an even number and $n\ne 0$.
2. When $n=2$, the statement is true.
3. When $n$ is even and $n>2$,  the statement is false.

**Sketch of Proof:**

1. There always exist $a,b\in\Bbb R$, such that $Q(x)=P(ax,bx)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. If $Q$ is of odd degree, then $Q(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$, which contradicts to $P\ge 0$.
2. Since $(0,0)$ is the global minimum point of $P$, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. Therefore,  $P$ is a [positive definite quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_definite_form), and the conclusion follows easily.
3. Consider the example $P(x,y)=(x-y)^n+x^2+y^2$.